# how to get amount of scroll for a scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview

How do I get the amount of pixels which a user has scrolled in a scroll view. I have a scroll view which contains lot of texts. I also have a button at bottom of the screen. What I want is to change text on the button to the amount of scrolling done in the scroll view.

this is my scroll view:

```
 <ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollverbal"
    >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/verbalintro"
     android:textSize="15sp"
     />

    <View 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
    />

    <TextView 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/verqstns"
         android:textSize="15sp"
    />

  </LinearLayout>  

</ScrollView>
```

and my button is

```
 <Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:text="15" 
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:drawablePadding="-5sp"
android:paddingLeft="10sp"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/tick"
/>
```

I read that it can be done using `getScrollY()` method. but don't know how to use it programatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, where scrollX is scrolled pix in x axis and scrollY in Y axis

```
scrollX = scrollView.getScrollX();
scrollY = scrollView.getScrollY();
```

[Refer this for doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getScrollX%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

this may help you

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5966375/472336

set click listener for your btn findview by id your scroolview and on that call this method and set it as buttons text

Comment: like this:   
  final Button answer= (Button) findViewById(R.id.answernumber);
  
  answer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ScrollView scrver = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollverbal);
    int scrollposition = scrver.getScrollY();
    answer.setText(scrollposition);
   }
  });

Comment: all i want is the text should change as the user scrolls

Comment: For this you have to set text of button  inside scroll listener of your scrollview for that this link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/10713501/472336