# scrollView.getScrollY() always returns 0

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I want to know when my `ScrollView` is scrolled to the top.
This is what I tried:

```
  scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                int scrollX = scrollView.getScrollX(); //for horizontalScrollView
                int scrollY = scrollView.getScrollY();
                Log.d("TagFragment", "scrollY" + scrollY);
                mainFragment.setCanPullToRefresh(scrollY == 0);
            }
        });
```

the problem is: scrollY is nearly always 0. so it returns nearly always true. Some values are correct:

logcat:

```
D/TagFragment﹕ scrollY242
D/TagFragment﹕ scrollY0
D/TagFragment﹕ scrollY0
D/TagFragment﹕ scrollY0
D/TagFragment﹕ scrollY0
D/TagFragment﹕ scrollY0
D/TagFragment﹕ scrollY244
D/TagFragment﹕ scrollY0
D/TagFragment﹕ scrollY0
D/TagFragment﹕ scrollY0
D/TagFragment﹕ scrollY0
D/TagFragment﹕ scrollY0
D/TagFragment﹕ scrollY245
D/TagFragment﹕ scrollY0
D/TagFragment﹕ scrollY0
D/TagFragment﹕ scrollY0
D/TagFragment﹕ scrollY0
D/TagFragment﹕ scrollY0
D/TagFragment﹕ scrollY246
D/TagFragment﹕ scrollY0
```

how can I know 100% precisely what the offset is?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327087/how-to-get-the-current-y-offset-of-a-scrollview

Comment: Did that, but it didn't help.